# Dropbox Python API: download public Dropbox folder

Tags: path, python-requests, dropbox-api

I'm working with Dropbox's Python API.  My end goal is that, given a link to a public dropbox folder (not saved in my Dropbox account), my program can download each image to a local Desktop folder.

Many of the Dropbox API calls require a path.  I'm currently constructing a path by concatenating the folder ID and name as described: "A path relative to a folder's ID can be constructed by using a slash (e.g. 'id:abc123xyz/hello.txt')".   I do this by calling a post request to [/get_shared_link_metadata](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-get_shared_link_metadata) to receive the ID and name.

Hover, when I attempt downloading (via the following code):

```
with open("/Users/______/Desktop/ok.jpeg", "wb") as f:
    metadata, res = dbx.files_download(path='id:jSheWaU4yeYAAAAAAAADHw/DSC_0190.JPG')
    f.write(res.content)
```

I get this error:

> dropbox.exceptions.ApiError:
>   ApiError('6c829586fd97ebc6e18aa40336e3aa94', DownloadError('path',
>   LookupError('not_found', None)))

Any insight would be appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That is the valid syntax for constructing a path to a file relative to the parent folder's ID.

This error indicates that this path doesn't exist in the connected user's account though. A few things to check in that case:

- If `id:jSheWaU4yeYAAAAAAAADHw` the ID of the file or the parent folder? If it is the ID of the file itself, you don't need to append the filename, and should instead supply `id:jSheWaU4yeYAAAAAAAADHw` only.
- Is there something at that path in the connected user's account? Make sure that you have the correct file name (assuming `id:jSheWaU4yeYAAAAAAAADHw` is the ID of the parent folder), that there is something at that path, and that you are looking at the correct account.

Comment: I'm actually trying to download public folders that are not in the connected user's account, and that's why I don't know what to put as the "path" for them.  I just revised the language in my post to be more clear.

Comment: The `files_download` method can only access files in the connected user's account. You can instead download a file from a shared link using [`sharing_get_shared_link_file`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moduledoc.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.sharing_get_shared_link_file).

Comment: I have tried sharing_get_shared_link_file, but I get the error "shared_link_is_directory", because that function only works on file objects.  I'm trying to access the files within a folder, given a URL to a folder.  What's difficult here is that all of the functions related to searching within a folder assume that the folder is in the connected user's account, and require the folder's path.

Comment: If the link is for a folder, you can specify a file inside the folder using `sharing_get_shared_link_file`'s `path` parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  How can I get a list of file names within each folder, so that I can generate the path to the specific file?

Comment: The API doesn't currently return a file listing like that unfortunately, but I'll pass this along as a feature request.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Dropbox API v2 now supports listing the contents of a shared link for a folder. This can be accomplished using the same interface as listing a folder in a connected user's account, via the list_folder functionality. To list the contents of a shared link for a folder, you instead provide the shared link URL in the `shared_link` parameter to [`list_folder`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder).